# Java issue using classes and accessing variables

Tags: java, class, methods, while-loop

I am currently enrolled in a Java class. The project we are tasked with is to code a program in which the total yearly salary is figured by way of a fixed annual salary, input for sales made in the year, and a percentage of the sales that is earned as commission. My issue is which variable should I use to get the correct output for the Total Compensation column in the table. I cannot figure out how to output the correct figure using the number from the other column and utilizing my logic from the other class. Here is my code so far, each class is a separate Java file:

```
package sales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sales {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initialise scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your annual sales:");

    // Read sales from input & calculate salary
    double annualSales = input.nextDouble();
    double salary = Utils.calculateSalary(annualSales);

    // Calculate commission bonus
    double commissionBonus = 1.5 * annualSales;

    // Print information for user
    System.out.println("The total yearly salary is: " + Utils.numFormat(salary));
    System.out.println("Total Sales \t\t Total Compensation");

    while (annualSales <= commissionBonus) {
        System.out.println(annualSales + " \t\t " + salary);
        annualSales += 5000;

        // Update salary according to annual sales
        salary = Utils.calculateSalary(annualSales);
    }

    // Close scanner
    input.close();
}
}

package sales;

/**
 *
 * @author etw11
 */
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Utils {
     public final static double FIXED_SALARY = 30000;
/**
 * @param dec
 * @return 
 */
public static String numFormat(double dec) {
    return new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00").format(dec);
}

/**
 * Calculates the salary based on the given sales.
 * @param sales The annual sales
 * @return The calculated salary.
 */
public static double calculateSalary(double sales) {
    double commissionRate = 0.10d;

    if (sales < 320000) {
        commissionRate = 0.00d;
    } else if (sales >= 320000 && sales < 400000) {
        commissionRate = 0.08d;
    }

    // System.out.println("The current commission is " + (int)(commissionRate * 100) + "% of total sales.");

    return FIXED_SALARY + (sales * commissionRate);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, if this is what you want, but you would need to update your `total` within the loop to update the value in the `Total Compensation` column.

Let's start with the little things you should change first. The [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) in Java is camel-case. You should change that accordingly. For example, rather than `getsalesDouble` you should name your function `getSalesDouble` - similar to your `numFormat`.

Next, you should also change the names of your methods and parameters/variables. In order to do that, I like to ask myself *what is this method going to do?*. Once I know that I'd come up with an appropriate verb for it and that's my method's name. For example, your `Calculator` should be named `calculate` in order to have a verb. But this wouldn't be self-explanatory, thus, another name has to take its place -- ask youself *what does it calculate?* (e.g. `calculateSalary`).

Next, your `utilsCalculate` class should start with an uppercase letter (see link above). I'd prefer to name it `Utils`, since there is only one utils class anyway. Additionally, the class should have only static methods, so you do not need to create an instance (see code below). You might want to create a *private default constructor*, to avoid other programmers in your team accidentally creating an instance of your `Utils` class.

Now, that being said, you should avoid commenting like you do. It only clutters your code. For example, the end of a method is indicated by `}`. So, there is no need to state that the end of the method is at the line where the `}` occurs. If you find it hard to see where the closing `}` of a method is, you might consider properly formatting your code. Usually your IDE can do that for you by pressing a shortcut or using the menu bar.

Last but not least, I take it, your code works for you, but the `total` does not update (within your `while loop`). This is, because you only calculate the total *once* and never re-calculate it with the new value of `salesDouble`. You'll have to call `total = salesObject.Calculator();` after updating the `salesDouble` value. Of course, this would require you to create a new `utilsCalculate` instance. Otherwise, the value would always be the same, as you would never update the `salesDouble` within your utils class. That is nothing I'd recommend you to do, but would solve your issue for the code as is.

Have this example, on how to do it *properly**.

**Utils**

```
package utils;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Utils {
    public final static double FIXED_SALARY = 30000;

    /**
     * Formats the given decimal number.
     * @param dec The number to format
     * @return The formatted number as string.
     */
    public static String numFormat(double dec) {
        return new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00").format(dec);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the salary based on the given sales.
     * @param sales The annual sales
     * @return The calculated salary.
     */
    public static double calculateSalary(double sales) {
        double commissionRate = 0.10d;

        if (sales < 320000) {
            commissionRate = 0.00d;
        } else if (sales >= 320000 && sales < 400000) {
            commissionRate = 0.08d;
        }

        // System.out.println("The current commission is " + (int)(commissionRate * 100) + "% of total sales.");

        return FIXED_SALARY + (sales * commissionRate);
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
package sales;

import java.util.Scanner;

import utils.Utils;

public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialise scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your annual sales:");

        // Read sales from input & calculate salary
        double annualSales = input.nextDouble();
        double salary = Utils.calculateSalary(annualSales);

        // Calculate commission bonus
        double commissionBonus = 1.5 * annualSales;

        // Print information for user
        System.out.println("The total yearly salary is: " + Utils.numFormat(salary));
        System.out.println("Total Sales \t\t Total Compensation");

        while (annualSales <= commissionBonus) {
            System.out.println(annualSales + " \t\t " + salary);
            annualSales += 5000;

            // Update salary according to annual sales
            salary = Utils.calculateSalary(annualSales);
        }

        // Close scanner
        input.close();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Please enter your annual sales:320000
The total yearly salary is: 55.600,00
Total Sales          Total Compensation
320000.0         55600.0
325000.0         56000.0
330000.0         56400.0
335000.0         56800.0
340000.0         57200.0
345000.0         57600.0
350000.0         58000.0
355000.0         58400.0
360000.0         58800.0
365000.0         59200.0
370000.0         59600.0
375000.0         60000.0
380000.0         60400.0
385000.0         60800.0
390000.0         61200.0
395000.0         61600.0
400000.0         70000.0
405000.0         70500.0
410000.0         71000.0
415000.0         71500.0
420000.0         72000.0
425000.0         72500.0
430000.0         73000.0
435000.0         73500.0
440000.0         74000.0
445000.0         74500.0
450000.0         75000.0
455000.0         75500.0
460000.0         76000.0
465000.0         76500.0
470000.0         77000.0
475000.0         77500.0
480000.0         78000.0
```

* Of course, there is still room for enhancement, but I think it should be sufficient for your problem.

**Note** that I did not check your equations, as I do not know how to calculate this - I assumed your calculations are correct.

Comment: This code keeps having issues. It throws an error when in this statement double annualSales = input.nextDouble(); It keeps saying the method should be static.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code as is? If so, there shouldn't be any issues.  Anyway, I'm guessing that you put your `input` outside of the `main` method. If you did so, you'll need to declare the `input` as `static`, i.e. `private static Scanner input`.

Comment: I didn't do a complete copy and paste but I did include both parts within the sales package and took out the import utils within the Person class.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say what's wrong without seeing your code. Did you resolve the issue already? Putting both classes within the same package, as well as having both classes within one file should work just fine.

Comment: I updated the code up top. As it states I am also adding array or arraylist with input for both. We are required to have multiple people asking for names, salary info as before, and comparisons between salaries earned.

Comment: Where does it state that? It seems, I can't find it. And what do you mean _input for both_? What's _both_? Also, in your question it doesn't say anything about _multiple people asking for names_ and _comparing salaries_.

Comment: I thought that when I updated my code above it would show the comments I made as well but it did not. The extended requirements are that the code will take information for multiple employees, asking for their name and annual sales made and put that information within an array or arraylist. The program will compare at least two of the employees and then calculate the additional sales that would be necessary to match or exceed the higher of the two employees compared. The table is optional.

Comment: Well, in that case you should use a `do-while` loop and simply read the input of the user (using your `input` variable)  until a certain string/number was entered (e.g. _stop_ or _-1_). Add the read input to a list (e.g. `employees.add(new Employee(readName, readAnnualSales);` If there were at least 2 employees entered (check with `employees.size()`) compare them. Use a new utility function for that (e.g. `compareEmployees(List<Employee> employees){...}`). **Note** that _Employee_ is another class providing a proper data structure.

Comment: How would I incorporate an array or arraylist into this? It seems that the new utility function would go into the Employee class?

Comment: Define your list as `List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();` somewhere in your `main` method. Use `do{ /*read input & add new employee to list*/} while(/*read input not stop word*/);` to add the `Employee` to the list. The utility function can be at any place, really - it depends on your coding style. I, for one, would create a method within `Employee`, namely `compare(Employee other)` which compares _this_ to the _other_ employee and returns the one with the higher sales. The `Utils` class would then have the method `compareEmployees` described above.